# How to use @inheritParams when expanding primitive functions in R

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

I want to document a new method using R S4 system, for example `sqrt()` :

```
##' Extend sqrt
##'
##' @title sqrt for myClass
##' @inheritParams sqrt
##' @return A numeric vector.
##' @exportMethod sqrt
##' 
setMethod(f = 'sqrt',
          signature = 'myClass',
          definition = function(x) {
            ...
          })
```

When I executed `devtools::document()`, I got a warning message like `Warning: @inheritParams: can't find topic sqrt`. I would like to know how to correctly use `@inheritParams` in such case.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old topic but it can maybe help others...
As far as I know, to copy parameter defintion from another function, you may use `@inheritParams fun` when the function exists in your package.
If this is not the case, you may use `@inheritParams package::fun`